# Pointers giving errors when building an old unix C project in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, pointers

I have an old C project that compiles just fine in Unix. I want to build it in Xcode on Lion, so I created a new Xcode project and added all of the files (except for the makefile).

At any rate, I am running into a number of 'Semantic Issues' while building. Does anyone know what could be going on here? All of these problems with pointers, seems odd. Is it really that different building a project in Xcode than using make? Does this have something to do with osx?

For example:

```
unsigned char *p = b->buf + adbuf_used(b);
```

gives the error:

> Initializing 'unsigned char *' with an expression of type 'char *'
>   converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

And

```
printf("sizeof(unsigned int) = %d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
```

gives the error:

> Conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned

And

```
printf("%2d, ", p-cset);
```

gives the error:

> Conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long'

And

```
if (getsockname(sock_rt, (struct sockaddr *)&iface_out, &len) == -1 ) {
```

gives the error:

> Passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int
>   *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors from the compilers are shown because this compiler is more strict, and by definition, it is right. In the cases you showed, you can change the following:

1. `p` and `b->buff` are not of the same type, `p` is of type `unsigned char *`, while `b->buff` is of type `char *`

   ```
   unsigned char *p = b->buf + adbuf_used(b);
   // To
   char *p = b->buf + adbuf_used(b);
   // or
   unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)b->buf + adbuf_used(b);
   ```
2. The format specifier for unsigned integers is `%u`, not `%d`. Or, as commented, in the case of `size_t` use `%zu`

   ```
   printf("sizeof(unsigned int) = %d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
   // to
   printf("sizeof(unsigned int) = %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
   ```
3. The format specifier for long is `%ld`, not `%d`

   ```
   printf("%2d, ", p->cset);
   // to
   printf("%2ld, ", p->cset);
   ```
4. The 3rd parameter is of type `socklen_t *`, not `int *`

   ```
   if (getsockname(sock_rt, (struct sockaddr *)&iface_out, &len) == -1 )
   //instead of 
   int len;
   // define
   socklen_t len;
   ```

All those cases will usually cause no harm if stayed as-is, but basically `unsigned` and `signed` are different types, and `long` and `int` are different types (it actually matters in  many systems)

Comment: As yes, that makes a lot of sense. I'll add some casting and see if everything works.

Comment: I would fix the types instead of using casting everywhere.

Comment: The format used to print the sizeof argument should be "%zu". The "z" modifier indicates the size_t integer type, which is not necessarily either unsigned int (%u) or unsigned long (%lu).

Answer (score 1):

At least one of `b->buf` and `adbuf_used(b)` is either a plain `char` or a `signed char`.

The specifier for unsigned integers in `printf` is `u`.

The specifier `d` assumes the argument is of type `int` whereas `p-cset` (?) is of type `long`. Use `l` instead.

The `getsockname` is again a similar enough error which you can figure out by yourself.

Read the manual for `printf`. And honor compiler warnings.